# Saving Data on iCloud

Tags: xcode, icloud, save, uidocument

I have been able to sync a plist to iCloud with all the user's level high scores.

I still haven't been able to figure out how to make it so people cannot just go into iCloud docs folder and change those values.

I know Jetpack Joyride saves their game information to iCloud, but when I go into the documents folder, there is nothing in there (do they save it to their own servers?)

Another game I have saves with a "Game.sav" file.

Is there a folder you can save to in iCloud that users cannot access? It would ruin the game if they could change their high score or achievement numbers for Game Center.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the document-saving feature of iCloud, use the key-value feature of iCloud (NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore). Users can't see that.

Comment: I was thinking of using that but would it be able to handle 50+ levels of high scores (i know there is a limit to the space and I don't know exactly how much that would take up.) 

Also, the docs state that it shouldn't be frequent saving (it would save every time the user wins a level). Do you have experience with the key-value feature and my worries are null and void?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make a file containing your 50+ levels of high scores and *see* how big it is?

Comment: I guess that answers my question then, thanks! I hope it works out :)